# UITableViewCell image view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, right-to-left

I have created `UITableView` with own custom `UITableViewCell` ,I have a .xib file for `UITableViewCell` and my application language is right to left I want to show `UIImageView` in right side of the cell and customize my cell for this purpose. But when in `UITableView` change table view mode and select cell, my image view is shown in left side of cell and changes this position, where is the problem?

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  PersonnelCell *cell = (PersonnelCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PersonnelCell"];
  NSMutableArray *cells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[PersonnelCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"PersonnelCell"];
  }
  cell.cellImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"];

  NSArray *personnels = [[PersonelList sharedList] allPersonel];

  if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

    NSArray *a = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    a = [self.resultData firstObject];

    NSString *s = [[a objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString:@" "];
    s = [s stringByAppendingString: [a objectAtIndex:1]];

    cell.nameLabel.text = s;
    if ([[a objectAtIndex:2] isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {

        cell.cellImage.image=[a objectAtIndex:2];
    }
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: show your code and snapshot of simulator.

Comment: it may be because tableview reuse cell so when cell allocated second time it is using default cell.

Answer (score 0):

I just can't post a comment, it requires me to have 50 reps above. Anyway, to solve your problem, you must use constraints in your views. Applying constraints in Xibs is so much easier than doing it programmatically.

Comment: I am add constrain for all view in my cell

Answer (score 0):

Every cell has default Image View like    `cell.imageView`

probably you are setting image to default image view  of cell that's why it is in left

try to change the IBOutlet of your image view

if it is not work try to put constraints

top, leading ,and fixed width,height

Comment: I am try it. delete IBOutlet of image view in .h file and create new outlet for damage view with another name, also i have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:FAQCellIdentifier];

        if (!cell) {
            UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"FAQTableViewCell" bundle:nil];
            [tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:FAQCellIdentifier];
            cell = (MyTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:FAQCellIdentifier];
        }

        FAQ *oFAQ = [self.mainList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.lblTitle.text = oFAQ.question;
        cell.yourImgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: oFAQ.imgName];
        return cell;
    }
```

Also please check that you set the constraint of your imageView as top, trailing, fixed : width, height

Comment: my image view height and width is equal 30, when change image view state in app image view is 40*40,that mean my image view replace with cell.image view

Comment: @Qazal can you please show the your code and simulator screenshot?

Comment: my reputation is equal to 4 I can not add image.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "CustomCell.h"

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ID_CustomCell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil){

    cell = (CustomCell *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

return cell;
}
```

[Download custom cell from](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ooURy3zGWKNWk5NkR0UE1iYnM/view?usp=sharing)

[image]